# Why the feminine "la" in "se la jouer stratégique"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques, genre

> Si on veut **se la jouer stratégique** pour ne pas courir aux quatre coins de Paris, il faut optimiser son temps et faire tous les cadeaux au même endroit.

Although I don't see any feminine noun before this sentence, the author uses the feminine "la". Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Se la jouer* is a set phrase where the pronoun *la* is not defined, but it is usually admitted to represent *situation* or *affaire*, both being feminine nouns. The origin of the phrase is not known, and according to [this forum](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/le-jouer-la-jouer/) supposedly quite old as in *se la jouer fine*. Probably difficult to assert  whether we interpret *la* as meaning *situation* or *affaire* because *la* is feminine, or if *situation* or *affaire* was meant at the origin.

When used on its own, *se la jouer* means "to delude oneself" (older meaning I expect) or "to show off" (more recent meaning I would say). But when followed by an adverb or an adjective it rather means "to give the impression" "to act as if". In your quote we could translate the phrase by "if we want to be strategical about it", where "it" would not necessarily be defined (or could be understood as meaning "the situation").

Comment: @suiiurisesse  : Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait un rapport entre « jouer de bonheur » et l’expression toute faite « se la jouer ». Effectivement, comme je le dis, l'origine de « se la jouer » n'est pas connue. J'ai aussi consulté le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* et le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* qui ne donnent pas d'origine, ce qui explique que le TLF ne mentionne pas non plus, il ne donne que l'emploi transitif de « se jouer ».

Comment: @suiiurisesse I would say  https://www.question-orthographe.fr/ which is part of *Projet Voltaire* is trustworthy. They really have some experts answering.

Answer (score 3):

In French, there are various similar informal expressions with a *standalone* pronoun with no specific antecedent. The nouns in brackets are only implied:

- *se **la** couler douce*  -- {***vie***} -- *vivre tranquillement*
- *se **la** boucler* -- {***gueule***} -- *se taire*
- *se **les** geler* -- {***miches***} -- *se peler*
- *se **les** cailler* -- {***meules***} -- *avoir très froid*
- *se **la** péter*  -- {***bretelle***} -- *frimer*
- *se **la** raconter* -- {***???***} -- *frimer*

(Not to be confused with "*se **le** raconter*" with a different meaning, in which "*le*" has an antecedent)

- *se **la** coller derrière l’oreille* -- {***cigarette***} -- *perdre tout espoir*, (ou dans un contexte sexuel)

Comment: @suiiurisesse L'antécédent n'est jamais exprimé dans ces expressions et il n'est pas aussi spécifique que pourraient le laisser croire les mots entre accolades. Pour *se la péter*, *se la raconter* et *se la couler douce*, personne n'a vraiment en tête un antécédent quelconque. Ce sont des expressions toutes faites, comme *se la jouer*. Pour ce qui concerne *se les geler* ou *se la coller derrière l'oreille*, d'autres antécédents que ceux cités sont probablement plus couramment sous-entendus. Il n'y a que *se cailler les meules* qui me semble assez fermé.

Comment: An hypothesis: "se la raconter" = se raconter l'histoire

Comment: @suiiurisesse Oui, bien sûr, toutes ces expressions sont forcément nées avec un antécédent. Chercher à le retrouver est intéressant et c'est bien l'objet de la question. J'ai découvert ici que c'était à l'origine une bretelle que l'on se pétait, ce qui était jusque là mystérieux pour moi (et pour toutes les personnes de mon entourage, l'origine étant semble-t-il québécoise).

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, DHLF confirme ça. Par ailleurs il évoque un truc que je connais pas, _la péter_ (la faim, soif), pour _mourir de_ puis _avoir très_. Les constructions réflexives avec le complément implicite sont toutes inhabituelles pour moi. Le singulier pour brettelle aussi, pcq. c'est relié à un geste pour moi, quand quelqu'un a des bretelles il bombe le torse puis glisse les pouces sous les bretelles et les tire vers l'avant, comme un signe de fierté/vantardise, un geste de mise en valeur, trop et ça peut briser, j'ai déjà vu ça au théâtre, mais on fait ça avec les deux mains. Intéressant.

Answer (score 2):

Comme le verbe [*jouer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jouer) peut vouloir dire « se livrer à tel ou tel jeu, avec une ou plusieurs personnes » (Wiktionnaire), peut-être que de manière implicite on réfère à l'idée de [*partie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/partie), nom féminin, l'« affrontement ludique entre deux ou plusieurs personne » (Wiktionnaire), comme dans une (jouer une) *partie d'échecs, de poker* etc. Il est peut-être moins usuel de jouer stratégiquement une *balle* ou une *carte*, mais ce sont aussi, entre autres, des noms féminins référant à des objets que l'on peut « jouer ». Évidemment, on ne parle pas concrètement d'un jeu ici, mais on semble associer l'activité dont il est question à une partie d'un jeu, au figuré. C'est l'équivalent de « [faire preuve](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_preuve)/[user](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/user) de stratégie » dans l'action en question afin d'éviter une conséquence (*courir aux quatre coins de Paris*). Enfin, plus précisément, l'optimisation est une stratégie. Quant à l'expression « jouer stratégique », avec l'adjectif, c'est il me semble une manière informelle de dire *jouer avec stratégie* ou *stratégiquement* ; on trouve ça sur internet, entre autres, quand donne des conseils avec différents types de jeux etc.